# How to get total hours from three shifts in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-query-store

I have three shift and i want total hours from each shift excluding break time,I tried with below query and i'm getting correct output for first two shifts but when 3rd shift coming its getting wrong output.

```
SELECT (SUM(CAST(CONVERT(float, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, t.FromTime, t.ToTime), 0), 114)as float)*60*24)-SUM(t1.test) )
            FROM ShiftTimes t RIGHT JOIN(select 
            SUM(CAST(CONVERT(float, DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, FromTime, ToTime), 0), 114)as float)*60*24)as test,ShiftId
            FROM StdBreaksInShifts group by ShiftId )t1 ON t.shiftid=t1.shiftid
            WHERE t1.shiftid=3
```

I have below shift times in the table,Please suggest how to calculate..

[image]

Comment: How would anyone else know if the results are correct or not?  Either add a Fiddle of some sort or add sample data and desired results to your question.  Also, explain the logic that you want to implement.  Further, your query returns one column but you have data with three columns.  Very unclear.

Comment: If user pass the shift id then query return total hours of that shift but in my case i got negative values for 3rd shift.

Comment: Can you share the schema of the two tables.